# Would SpaceX's Starlink constellation contribute inordinately to space debris?

Tags: spacex, debris, starlink

I mean they already launched a large constellation of 60 satellites and have plans to launch many more; won't all this contribute inordinately to existing space junk, which is actually becoming a real big issue in recent years?

Do they have a proposed plan on how to dispose off those satellites once their lifetime is over?

Comment: Yes, fear not! Search for the word "deorbit" in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starlink_(satellite_constellation)

Answer (score 4):

They have assured the FCC in [this letter](https://licensing.fcc.gov/myibfs/download.do?attachment_key=1636825), and I guess the FAA as well that the low orbit they are in guarantees reentry in a short time period if they lose all control.

They certified that except for a couple of components, all are expected to burn up in reentry.

Specifically,

> The first version, comprising fewer than 75 satellites, will include an iron thruster and steel reaction wheels on each satellite.

The first 75 units have components that will NOT be certain to burn up entirely, but for the following units they have changed to ensure they do burn up as completely as is possible. (It is usually all about risk, and never about absolutes).

Comment: Sir do you know which components will not be certain to burn up in first 75 units? And what changes have they made in following units to ensure that those components burn up?

Comment: @Garima Edited to add in the reference to the source, and the specific components.

Comment: Thank you sir. Also, please can you tell me how they calculate the collision risk of incapacitated satellites?